# Requires MonadPlus (ST a) Instance

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, unification, st-monad, monadplus

I'm reading the paper [*Typed Logical Variables in Haskell*](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.2565), but I'm failing to understand the details of the ultimate implementation. In particular, the backtracking state transformer introduced in section 4. For some reason, unknown to me, GHC believes I require a `MonadPlus` instance for `(ST a)` in the function `unify`, below:

```
newtype BackT m a = BT { run :: forall b . (a -> m [b]) -> m [b] }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (BackT m) where
 return a   = BT (\k -> k a)
 BT m >>= f = BT (\k -> m (\a -> run (f a) k))

instance (MonadPlus m) => MonadPlus (BackT m) where 
 mzero             = BT (\s -> mzero)
 f `mplus` g = BT (\s -> (run f) s `mplus` (run g) s)

type LP a = BackT (ST a)
type LR   = STRef

type Var s a = LR s (Maybe a)   
data Atom s = VarA (Var s (Atom s)) | Atom String

class Unify b a | a -> b where
 var   :: a -> Maybe (Var b a)
 unify :: a -> a -> LP s ()

instance Unify s (Atom s) where
 var (VarA a) = Just a
 var _        = Nothing

 unify (Atom a) (Atom b) | a == b = return () -- type checks
 unify _        _                 = mzero     -- requires MonadPlus (ST a) instance
```

I'm unsure what the problem is, and how to fix it. I was under the impression that I understood the preceding discussion and code until this point, but apparently I was mistaken. If someone could point out what's going awry - do I need a `MonadPlus (ST a)` instance or not? - it would be very helpful.

**[EDIT: Clarification]** I should have pointed out that the *authors* appear to claim that `mzero`, or some variation on `mzero`, is the appropriate function. I just don't know what the appropriate function is. What I'm wondering is whether I am supposed to make a `MonadPlus (ST a)` instance or I'm not using the correct function, and have misread something.

Comment: The return type of `unify` is `LP s ()`, or `BackT (ST a) ()`. So apparently the `BackT m` instance of `MonadPlus` requires `MonadPlus m`. Could you include that instance here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mzero` is a member of the typeclass `MonadPlus`. In particular

```
mzero :: MonadPlus m => m a
```

The monad that is used for your function `unify` is `LP`, which is actually `BackT` instantiated with `ST`. You furthermore define an instance of `MonadPlus` for `BackT`, that depends on such an instance for the underlying monad. Since `ST` has no such instance, GHC mocks you.

This is the important part:

```
instance (MonadPlus m) => MonadPlus (BackT m) where 
  mzero             = BT (\s -> mzero)
  f `mplus` g = BT (\s -> (run f) s `mplus` (run g) s)
```

In plain english: This is an instance of `MonadPlus` for `BackT m`, provided that `m` is also an instance of `MonadPlus`. Since `m` is instanciated with `ST`, you need that instance for `ST`. I wonder how you could define a sensible instance of `MonadPlus` without delegation. I have an idea:

```
instance MonadPlus (BackT m) where
  mzero = BT (const $ return [])
  mplus (BT f) (BT g) = BT $ \a -> do
    fs <- f a
    gs <- g a
    return $ fs ++ gs
```

This instance basically concatenates the two output lists. I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: You're correct; I've updated my post to include the definitions. It's possible I've misunderstood the monad and defined bind, return, mzero or plus incorrectly.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for explaining the problem and the solution.

Comment: Be careful!  This MonadPlus definition may not be what you expect.  Intermediate writes to `STRef`s in a branch that eventually fails will *not* roll back.

Comment: @luqui is correct; if you try and use the regular `writeSTRef` in one branch, its effects will be seen in the other. To avoid this, use the `writeLPRef` definition in section 4.2. It wraps the `BackT` continuation in what's essentially a failure continuation in order to make `mplus` for `ST` seem commutative. This is just a matter of discipline, though, rather than `ST` really being a well-behaved `MonadPlus` instance.

Answer (score 3):

The `BackT` `MonadPlus` instance probably should use the `MonadPlus` instance of `[]` instead of `m`, like this:

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadPlus (BackT m) where 
  mzero       = BT (\_ -> return mzero)
  f `mplus` g = BT (\s -> liftM2 mplus (run f s) (run g s))
```